# Install a i386 printer driver into an amd64 distribution or how can I find a good printer based on features?

Tags: hardware, drivers, printing

I just bought a Lexmark Interpret S408 all-in-one printer. The box said that it supported Ubuntu 8.04, but I told myself it *should* work with Lucid... well no. The only driver I have found is for i386 while I have a amd64 image installed; the architecture is incompatible.

So, the quesiton is : <del>Is it possible to install that driver anyway, somehow? Or</del> do I need to take that printer back to the store and buy another one?

<del>If the latter is the only alternative,</del> I need a printer that

- has wireless connection capability
- can do color printing
- is of good price (less than $200 CAD)

Thank you for your answers, help, and tips.

** **UPDATE** **

The driver was given in the form of deb package (for Debian distributions) and I managed to extract the actual deb package driver out of the install program. I ran

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all lexmark-inkjet-09-driver-1.5-1.i386.deb
```

and the driver installed, and I was able to print something out. But that pretty much ends there; I cannot access anymore of the printer settings, etc. (i.g. scanner, fax, wifi settings, etc.) I should suffice for now as I'm satisfied with the printer's features (and size, and prince), but if I could have a full-linux-supported printer like that one, I would return this one in exchange for the other.

Comment: What kind of driver were you provided (.deb/.tar.gz/etc), and where did you get it from?

Comment: @Jacob, both. The deb is embedded into a deb.sh, which is in turn provided as a tar.gz to download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to look for hardware that's supported by drivers shipping with Linux distributions, than to select hardware because its manufacturer advertises Linux support. That's because hardware manufacturers aren't always very good at writing drivers, especially for non-Windows OSes. Beware especially of binary-only drivers: they're hard to integrate with anything but the particular distribution the driver maker tested their code with.

For printers, favor one that's on the [Gutenprint supported list](http://gutenprint.sourceforge.net/p_Supported_Printers.php). Sometimes a newer model now available in stores hasn't made it into the list yet, but a slightly older model is supported and the driver works with the newer model. Postscript printers (rare in your price range) are always ok. Otherwise, beware; Google to see if other people have gotten it to work before buying.

The Gutenprint compatibility list is short on Lexmark models. You *can* still try to print and see what happens, and search or ask on the Gutenprint lists to see what people think of your model. If it's definitely not supported by Gutenprint, install the i386 driver, even if you have an amd64 installation: amd64 kernels can run 32-bit programs, and the libraries a driver is likely to use are in the `ia32-libs` package.

Comment: I hear that, and I've been searching in forums and other Ubuntu document wiki to find a printer fitting my needs, however most of them can't be found in stores anymore, etc. Lists are great, but doesn't say the user appreciation nor give reviews of printers. The fact is that I went looking for a specific printer, didn't find it anywhere and ended up buying that Lexmark one because no one knew Linux enough to help me. I mean, programming a "find a printer based on features" tool shouldn't be too hard to code... Linux works great, but the printer part of it is really behind and not user friendly

Comment: @Yanick: My usual procedure when buying hardware is to find likely candidates, then check Linux support for the specific candidate models (generally ignoring manufacturers' statements on Linux support). Programming a “find a printer based on features” tool is not hard, the difficulty is collecting all the data (you'll notice that Microsoft doesn't do it either).